# Use PayPal (Sandbox) Order ID to open CheckOut via Smart Payment Buttons

Tags: node.js, paypal

I have integrated PayPal in my backend to get an Order ID. How can I use this Order ID on the client side via Smart Payment Buttons to open the CheckOut?

The following line has worked recently, but not for a few days since the order ID is accepted as a token. Paypal has changed something.

```
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: (data: any, actions: any) => {
    return myOrderID; (from Server Side)
  },
  onApprove: async (data: any, actions: any) => {
    ... 
  },
  onError: (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
  }).render(
    this.paypalElement.nativeElement
);
```

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an official demo sample that uses a fetch: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

It looks like your (incomplete) code example ought to work , but since it's not complete and hence runnable it can't be tested

I would encourage you to work from the official sample and either build it into your solution or adapt it to be more like the code you want to run and produce a testable sample of your own

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I can reproduce my problem on "https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server". I replaced "client-id" with my own and wrote `createOrder: function (data, actions) {return 'myOrderID'}`. The checkout window / tab opens only briefly and closes again. It wasn't like that a month ago. I'll try to find another solution tonight.

Comment: This portion of your code is right, so something else is preventing the payment from proceeding. Open dev tools and log the errors, particularly any debug messages and their debug/correlationIDs.  Use the Network tab with [x] Preserve Log and look at response bodies and Response headers if you have to.

Comment: Thanks again! I solved the problem. You're right, you just have to debug and read the error message carefully.